# How would you go about finding longest string per row in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a piece of code which allows me to open a CSV file, remove nan rows and also find strings that are too long in the data frame. I want the program to say what row the length of data exceeds the 30-character limit and give you an option to exit or skip.

I previously had it set up so it would go by columns instead, however I'm finding it difficult to locate the string when it's set up like this.

```
for column in df:
        print(column,"->", df[column].astype(str).str.len().max())
        if df[column].astype(str).str.len().max() > 30 and column != ('Column 17'):
            print ("ERROR: Length of data exceeds 30 character limit")
            abill=int(input("1.Continue through file.\n2.Exit\n"))
            if abill==1:
                continue
            else:
                sys.exit()
        else:
            continue
```

This is my code at the moment.

Comment: Does it need to be in a loop?

Comment: No, I was just using that as I found it easier.

Comment: OK, then have a look at my proposed answer and let me know if this would work for you, or what would be missing (ideally with a small example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not to use a loop, but rather to vectorize.

So, you want to identify the strings longer than a threshold, except for excluded columns?

Assuming this example:

```
        col1        col2              col3
0        abc           A  this_is_excluded
1  defghijkl       BCDEF          excluded
2       mnop  GHIJKLMNOP          excluded
```

If you want to **mask** the long strings:

```
exclude = ['col3']  # do not consider the columns in this list
threshold = 9       # consider strings longer or equal to threshold

mask = (df.drop(columns=exclude, errors='ignore')
          .apply(lambda s: s.str.len().ge(threshold))
          .reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=False)
       )

out = df.mask(mask, '') # mask with empty string
```

Output:

```
   col1   col2              col3
0   abc      A  this_is_excluded
1        BCDEF          excluded
2  mnop                 excluded
```

If you want to **drop** the rows with long strings:

```
exclude = ['col3']
threshold = 9

mask = (df.drop(columns=exclude, errors='ignore')
          .apply(lambda s: s.str.len().ge(threshold))
        )

out = df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2              col3
0  abc    A  this_is_excluded
```

If you want to drop the **columns** with at least one too long string:

```
exclude = ['col3']
threshold = 9

mask = (df.drop(columns=exclude, errors='ignore')
          .agg(lambda s: s.str.len().ge(threshold).any())
       )

out = df.drop(columns=mask[mask].index)
```

Output:

```
               col3
0  this_is_excluded
1          excluded
2          excluded
```